# How to sign assembly and exe files in the installer package?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, installshield

I've made an application with test certificate and installer(with InstallShield limited edition).

In signing option of my project I've chosen options
* Sign the ClickOnce manifests,
* Sign the assembly.

In the installer project in signing tab I've chosen the same digital certificate file, entered password, and option sign output files : Setup.exe and Windows Installer Package.

Option Sign Files in Package is not available. So after installing my program, only Setup.exe and msi file are signed. How to make another exe files and assemblies with digital signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the assemblies you are installing, you need to sign them before building the installer. Visual studio can sign, or you can set up a post build step to sign them manually with signcode.

I recommend visual studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sh96ycy(v=vs.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I tried both way and the problem is that when I build the installer, my files that are inside, are not signed, and I sign them on post build event with batch file(or using signing tab). Why it happens?

Comment: Partly it depends on where your files are being pulled into the installer from. If you are copying your files as a post build step to an "installersource" (for example) but you sign your files in "project\bin", the installersource copy might happen before your signing takes place. Without seeing what you are doing I really don't have more ideas.